# Pre-Commit Hook Unit Test

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal, githooks

I am trying to run a pre-commit hook that prevents me from committing if my unit tests don't run. Right now I have a shell script that  runs the tests and my terminal tells me that they have failed, which is good. But I am not sure what to put in my Shell Script to actually stop my commit once my terminal detects that I have failing tests. 
Like this:
[image]

I am inclined to think that all I am missing is a simple if statement which checks if the tests fail then stop the commit and if the tests pass then complete the commit. But I could be completely wrong about that, and this is my first time working with shell scripts so I am not really sure how to go about doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Your test command will usually return a failing exit code.  So either make it the last thing in your script, or put `set -e` at the top of your script, or put `|| exit 1` after it

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure your script exits with a non-zero exit code when the tests fail.

From the Git docs:

> Exiting with a non-zero status from this script causes the git commit command to abort before creating a commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Basically, do `exit 1` if the tests fail and `exit 0` otherwise. Right now, you're probably doing `exit 0` (or just letting the script end) in all cases.

Most likely, your unit tests are already returning a valid exit code, which you can use to determine the exit code for your script.

A simple way to do this is something like:

```
<run unit tests>
EXIT_CODE=$?
...
exit EXIT_CODE
```

Comment: I understand the different exit codes, but I am still not totally clear what to put in the if statement.
So like here is my understanding of the situation now.  Just to put this in pseudo code:
  if  *testsFail* {
     exit 1
  } else {
      exit 0
  }
Should I even be bothering with an if statement? And if so what should I put in the conditional part of it? Thank You

Comment: `if testsFail { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }` — that's ok. Or you can do `testFail && exit 1 || exit 0`.

Comment: @phd but what would I write instead of testFail in the if statement? I just wrote testFail as a pseudo code example. Not really sure what I should actually write after the keyword if to really check if the test is failing or not. Sorry if I'm not being clear :(

Comment: How do we know? We don't see any code in your question…

Comment: Perhaps provide more detail. Specifically, which command are you using to run your tests, and what does your script do after running that command? Also, it may be helpful for you to know that the `$?` variable shows the last exit code. This works both in the terminal and in scripts.

Comment: @mkasberg So in my shell script all I have is this command: xcodebuild test -workspace Hooks.xcworkspace -scheme Hooks -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.3' And then my terminal tells me that the tests fail and commits the project, I have a screenshot of what is my terminal is showing in the original post. Apologies for the delayed response.

Answer (score 4):

This simple shell script in **.git/hooks/pre-commit** worked for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
npm run test || exit 1
```

If the npm run test fails it passes the control to exit which fails with positive error code to terminate the program. If it passes the exit statement is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

My .pre-commit-config.yaml file for maven project looks like below.

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/ejba/pre-commit-maven
    rev: v0.3.3
    hooks:
    -   id: maven-test
```

reference: https://github.com/ejba/pre-commit-maven

you can also checkout complete list of pre-hooks available [here](https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html), I am sure that there will be hook available to run unit test for the language you are looking, for instead of running unit test using shell script.